# How am I supposed to map through this array when the console says it's an object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, reddit

I'm trying to access and render some information from Reddit in a personal project and I'm confused why I get the error that I am getting. There are two areas of confusion for me.

1. The page won't render because it says that 'Objects are not valid as a React child'. It says that it's an object, but it really truly is an array. NOTE: I'm aware that arrays are objects, and I get why the second console log in the componentWillMount is returning 'object' - but in my console/Postman, it's showing that res.data.data.children is infact an array. Puzzled about how I can get it so I can map through it later.
2. Sometimes it's not rendering because it says that this.state.subreddits[0].data.title is not defined. My guess is that setState is not functioning as fast as the render, and is still undefined when the render method runs, but I'm struggling to find a remedy for it. Any hints?

   ```
   import React, {Component} from 'react';
   import axios from 'axios';


   export default class Home extends Component {
   constructor(props){
       super(props)

       this.state = {
           subreddits: []
       }
   }


   componentWillMount() {
   axios.get('https://www.reddit.com/best.json')
       .then((res) => {
           console.log(res.data.data.children[0].data.title)
           console.log(typeof(res.data.data.children))
           this.setState({
               subreddits: res.data.data.children
       })
   }) 
   }

   render(){        
   return(
       <p>{this.state.subreddits[0].data.title}</p>          

   )
   }
   }
   ```

Comment: Arrays are objects ... so, as you know it's an array, use it as an array

Comment: `typeof ([])` will evaluate to `object`.  They are a special kind of object, but [an object nonetheless](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

Comment: Thanks. Once I plugged in the map function, it worked... I was just confused why it kept telling me it was an object and not just displaying the info that it was supposed to.

Comment: With regards to your second point, you should do axios requests in `componentDidMount`, not `componentWillMount` (look up lifecycle methods and when to use them). With regards to the fact that it's not defined when you render so you get an error, you should never assume stuff exists. Check data and object properties first before trying to render them.

Comment: Just a side note: It's not advised to do such levels of dereferencing in a JSON tree. Use a safe method with proper error handling or use lodash's get method, sample syntax would be to set a fall back with null like so: `_.get(res, 'data.data.children[0].data.title',  null);` |--- This is important in case something breaks then react would unmount the whole tree leaving a blank white screen behind. :)

Answer (score 0):

React frowns upon the use of get requests in `componentWillMount` as it doesn't fire an additional render instead you should use `ComponentDidMount()` [more info](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount)